# How to handle MouseOver Event by Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium webdriver to automate my web application.I have[image] to handle mouse over event in my web application.So how to handle these.For clearafication screenshot is attached.
Acyually i have to select that particular by moving the mouse from left to right.Plz help me.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Actions API.

It will look something like this:

```
Actions actions  = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.someSelector()))
actions.otherActions();
actions.perform();
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: Actually i have to select that moving mouse from left to right and clicking on the right corner that will be selected.So that is not going to be recorded by selenium-IDE.so how to code for that in selenium webdriver.Plz help me.Plz see the screenshot above.

Comment: I would recommend looking at that link I gave you.  One of those functions will be able to click on an element based off of X/Y coordinates.

Comment: Can u please give me idea to find X/Y co-ordinate of any web element?

Comment: Its based off of the WebElement, with the top left corner of the WebElement 0,0. You can either take a screenshot and count the pixels, or guess and try.